# Для чего нужны саб-ключи в GPG?

Tags: linux, password, gpg

Всем форумчанам добрый вечер\день, во время просмотра видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CwsoGw2coc автор создал 4 саб ключа - Sign (S), Encrypt (E), Authentication (A) и еще один Encrypt (E) для шифрования паролей. Также автор сказал что можно использовать разные саб-ключи для разных целей, например, первым саб-ключем(S) подписывать документы, вторым саб-ключем(E) шифровать пароли, третим саб-ключем(A) авторизовываться на SSH серверах, а последний можно использовать чтобы шифровать только пароли(к примеру). Смысл в том чтобы использовать разные саб-ключи.

Но когда я создал ключ, а также добавил несколько саб-ключей, то был удивлен тем что при экспорте паблик-ключа и любого из саб-ключей выходит одинаковый текст.
Я использовал такие команды:

```
gpg -a --export <name> public_key.gpg
gpg -a --export <sub-key-number> > public_key.gpg
```

Где sub-key-number, это keyID (rsa4096/ < sub-key-number >)

Вопросы:

1. Разве каждый саб-ключ не должен отличаться от  другого? А также от основного public-ключа?
2. Если это я сделал что-то неправильно или неправильно понял, то каким образом можно использовать разные саб-ключи на разных сайтах? Например, как мне использовать первый саб-ключ (E) для шифрования паролей, второй (Е) для шифрования своих личных данных, а третий (На сколько я понимаю S) для подписей коммитов на GitHub?

Comment: удалось разобраться? я тоже не понял как именно саб ключи взаимодействуют с мастер ключом, что будет если они протухнут - я не смогу получить доступ к паролям? прежде чем использовать pass с сабключами хочется все досконально проверить чтобы не было потом проблем
может почитать что-то можно по этой теме?

Answer (score 0):

как я понимаю, чтобы явно указывать keyID (один или несколько) нужно ставить восклицательный знак после каждого keyID. Так:

```
gpg -a --export <keyID1>! <keyID2>! > public_key.gpg
gpg -e -r <keyID>! file
gpg -clearsign -u <keyID>! file
```

Иначе gpg считает keyID без восклицательного знака указателем на всю "связку" userID.